# Can you build convection currents out of hollow air?

Tags: science-based, geology, megastructures, currents, artificial-gravity

Recently, I found this image by the Redditor "Keeperofbeesandtruth":

[image]

He made it free to use, as he doesn't intend on being serious about his own project.

So here's my plan:  Keep the atmosphere, keep the crust, keep the hopefully alloy shell, ditch the dome entirely, artificially reduce the gravity to 1.0 (100% Earth's gravity) and replace the gas giant with some kind of reactor core, like something we'd see with the Death Star...

[image]

...or with the Enterprise.

[image]

This creates a lot of dead space between the core and the shell.  The focus of this question concerns the one thing that has been keeping our Earth moving and protecting it from the worst of radiation--convection currents.

[image]

Our mantle is a dense mass of molten rock, not an empty space of air.  So can convection currents be made in a hollow, airy mantle?

Comment: ...why not skip the convection currents, and have your handwavium "reactor core" generate a magnetic field directly?

Comment: @Qami  Because continents can't move without convection currents.

Comment: There's convection currents in oceans, the atmosphere, a saucepan of water on a stove... in fact any fluid that has temperature differentials.  However, your response to @Qami talks about continents moving - the continents can't move because they are sitting on a shell that needs to be fixed or everything will collapse into the centre of the planet.

Comment: If you "replace[d] the gas giant with some kind of reactor core" what are you creating convection cells *in*? The reactor?

Comment: You call for mantle convection without a mantle. To get the forces that move continents, you'd need something substantial below that crust. When you want 1g gravity on top of it, the crust will sustain enormous pressure and the construct needs to be solid and rigid anyway. Like an egg shell.

Comment: The center of the Earth IS a 'nuclear reactor'. https://www.nature.com/articles/news.2008.822

Answer (score 2):

**Liquid Hot Magma**

[image]

The megastructure goes: Reactor Core, dead space, unobtainium shell, magma (with convection currents), continents. The continents float on the magma just like the Earth.